# Safari Webdriver does throws an exception on initialization

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

I am working with Selenium safari webdriver. The tests were running fine and all of a sudden the safari webdriver is not working. I quit all the process of Safari instances. When initailising the webdriver two instances of the Safri browser opens up and then an exception is thrown as below.

Could not create a session: The Safari instance is already paired with another WebDriver session.

Comment: It sounds like you're opening more than 1 instance of WebDriver.  Post the code where you instantiate the Safari WebDriver.

Comment: The following is the code used to initiate the web driver. This is done in the PO class:                                                                               
  protected static WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();

Comment: This is working again now. Didn't do anything though. Thanks for the response.